# R data.table left-outer join, matching nearest

Tags: r, data.table, left-join

I've got two tables that I want to join by the closest timestamp. Some timestamps match exactly, but most do not. Larger examples of the data I'm working with can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Rf0AmWhg) and [here](https://pastebin.com/S9PmjYUG).

#### Table 1: eyeDatP1_final

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+--------------------+-------------+
| "team" | "block" | "trial" | "x.pos1" | "y.pos1" | "time" |      "time1"       | "condition" |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+--------------------+-------------+
|    910 |     1   |       1 |    7.012 |   19.034 |      0 |                  0 | "normal"    |
|    910 |     1   |       1 |    7.012 |   19.034 |      0 | 0.0900001525878906 | "normal"    |
|    910 |     1   |       1 |    7.012 |   19.034 |      0 |  0.180000066757202 | "normal"    |
|    910 |     1   |       1 |    7.012 |   19.034 |      0 |  0.279999971389771 | "normal"    |
|    910 |     1   |       1 |    7.012 |   19.034 |      0 |  0.370000123977661 | "normal"    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+--------------------+-------------+
```

#### Table 2: eyeDatP2_final

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| "team" | "block" | "trial" | "x.pos2" | "y.pos2" |      "time"       |      "time2"      | "condition" |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   72.656 | -136.216 |                 0 |                 0 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   71.398 | -139.887 | 0.070000171661377 | 0.070000171661377 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 |   68.219 | -146.002 | 0.170000076293945 | 0.170000076293945 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 | -166.067 |  125.859 | 0.259999990463257 | 0.259999990463257 | "normal"    |
|    910 |       1 |       1 | -164.175 |  112.627 | 0.360000133514404 | 0.360000133514404 | "normal"    |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

EDIT, this code works:

```
eyeDatP1_final <- setDT(eyeDatP1_final)
eyeDatP2_final <- setDT(eyeDatP2_final)
eyeDatP1_final$time.matched <- eyeDatP1_final$time1
eyeDatP2_final$time.matched <- eyeDatP1_final$time2
setkey(eyeDatP1_final, team, condition, trial, time.match)
setkey(eyeDatP2_final, team, condition, trial, time.match)
eyeDat_final <- eyeDatP1_final[eyeDatP2_final, roll = "nearest"]
```

Comment: You can check the `fuzzyjoin` package. It is used for non exact match on text fields. https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin

Comment: One reason that you don't get more answers is that the data are in a useless format. If you want to use `R`, make them R compatible!

Comment: I'll check out fussyjoin, thanks! Vaettchen, the two pastebin links I provided have the data in tab delimited format

Comment: Edited the question to show the correct way to do a left-outer join

Comment: Another good option is to use rolling joins from the data.table package - here is [a good tutorial](https://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins/)